# Import OpenSSL Generated Private Key into Oracle Wallet

Tags: oracle, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a private key that was created from an OpenSSL certificate signing request. The CA has accepted the CSR and given my the cert. When I try importing into my Oracle Wallet using orapki I get the error "No matching private key in the wallet". When I try importing the private key just as I would any user cert I get "Invalid Certificate". I've already added all the trusted certificates.

Here are the commands used:

```
orapki wallet add -wallet ewallet.p12 -user_cert -cert public.p12 
orapki wallet add -wallet ewallet.p12 -user_cert -cert private.txt
```

I'm assuming there's a way to add the private key to the wallet?

Comment: Private key is different from the cert. You cannot use the `-cert` option to input private key.

Comment: @Prabhu Okay, so how can I import a private key? I'm starting to think the problem is that the CSR was generated using OpenSSL instead of using Oracle Wallet Manager or orapki.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww, understood. Thanks.

Comment: @robhyx : Did you find out how to do this. Having same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot import a KEY.

The Key is part of the wallet already, you need to create the certificate request with ORAPKI, as the key will be part of the request.

You cannot create a certificate using a request from other wallet, and then try to install everything into a new wallet that already has a Key.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an orapki wallet from an openssl keystore as another method to bring in the private key.

```
orapki wallet create -wallet /path/to/wallet/wallet.p12 -auto_login [-pwd <password>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following syntax

```
orapki wallet import_pkcs12 
 –wallet wallet_location [-pwd wallet_password] 
 -pkcs12file pkcs12_file_location [-pkcs12pwd pkcs12_file_password]
```